# ElasticSearch combine Terms and Match query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have worked out the elasticsearch query I need via Console, and it works as expected:

```
                    "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                        { "terms": { "color": ["red", "blue"]
                            }
                        },
                        { "match": { "availability":   "in stock" }} 
                        ]
                    }
               }
```

I now need to do this using the nest client. I have currently tried:

```
                nestClient.Search<Item>(
                s => s.From(query.Page).Size(query.PageSize)
                    .Query(
                        q => q.Bool(
                            b => b.Must(
                                ss => ss.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Color).Terms<string>(query.Color)),
                                ss => ss.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Availability == "in stock"))))).TypedKeys(null));
```

But when looking at the outputted JSON in fiddler it seems to be ignoring the query and using:

```
{"from":0,"size":24}
```

If I remove the `match` part of the nest query then the outputted JSON DSL is correctly using the Terms query.

Is it possible to do what I am looking for in one pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query value for the [`match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/match-usage.html) needs to be passed to the `.Query(...)` method

```
var query = new {
    Page = 0,
    PageSize = 10,
    Color = new [] { "red", "yellow" }
};

nestClient.Search<Item>(s => s
    .From(query.Page)
    .Size(query.PageSize)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(
                ss => ss.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Color).Terms<string>(query.Color)),
                ss => ss.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Availability).Query("in stock"))
            )
        )
    )
    .TypedKeys(null)
);
```

This can be shortened further using [operator overloading on the base query type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html), to construct a `bool` query more succinctly

```
nestClient.Search<Item>(s => s
    .From(query.Page)
    .Size(query.PageSize)
    .Query(q => q
        .Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Color).Terms<string>(query.Color)) && q
        .Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Availability).Query("in stock"))
    )
    .TypedKeys(null)
);
```

Both will produce the following query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "color": [
              "red",
              "yellow"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "availability": {
              "query": "in stock"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, with [term-level queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/term-level-queries.html) like `terms` query, the answer to the query is typically yes or no e.g. does this term match exactly, is this number in this range of numbers, etc. With predicates like this, you typically don't need the relevancy scoring phase to be executed for these queries, which you can forgo by having them execute in a `filter` context, such as the filter clause of a `bool` query. Putting this together with operator overloading

```
nestClient.Search<Item>(s => s
    .From(query.Page)
    .Size(query.PageSize)
    .Query(q => q
        .Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Color).Terms<string>(query.Color)) && +q
        .Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Availability).Query("in stock"))
    )
    .TypedKeys(null)
);
```

which yields

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "color": [
              "red",
              "yellow"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "availability": {
              "query": "in stock"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Russ for explaining the need for a query value, you example has helped, though I am still getting results back that aren't only "in stock"?

Comment: You can check why a document matches (or doesn't) for a particular query with the Explain API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html. My suspicion without knowing your data or how it is mapped, is that the `match` query probably ought to be a `term` query, to match a value _exactly_. Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html