# calling elastic search query from frontend with multiple query params

Tags: javascript, python, elasticsearch

## API Usage:

I am using a public API to display artworks on frontend. The public API url: https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search

## Scenarios that works individually

To filter artworks that has `place_of_origin=France`, I can use this query (works 100% fine): [https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?fields=id,api_link,title,description,thumbnail,image_id,place_of_origin&page=1&limit=10&query[match][place_of_origin]=france](https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?fields=id,api_link,title,description,thumbnail,image_id,place_of_origin&page=1&limit=10&query%5Bmatch%5D%5Bplace_of_origin%5D=france)

To search artworks whose `title includes night`, I can use this query (works 100% fine):
[https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?fields=id,api_link,title,description,thumbnail,image_id,place_of_origin&page=1&limit=10&query[term][title]=night](https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?fields=id,api_link,title,description,thumbnail,image_id,place_of_origin&page=1&limit=10&query%5Bterm%5D%5Btitle%5D=night)

## Combining two query params gives problems

Now, If I want to filter artworks that. has `place_of_origin=France` as well as I want to search artworks whose `title includes night` in the same api call. So, here is the url that I call GET request on: [https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?fields=id,api_link,title,description,thumbnail,image_id,place_of_origin&page=1&limit=10&query[term][title]=night&query[match][place_of_origin]=france](https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?fields=id,api_link,title,description,thumbnail,image_id,place_of_origin&page=1&limit=10&query%5Bterm%5D%5Btitle%5D=night&query%5Bmatch%5D%5Bplace_of_origin%5D=france)

It gives me 400 Bad request.

Here is the exact response that I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
                "line": 1,
                "col": 416
            }
        ],
        "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason": "[1:416] [bool] failed to parse field [must]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
            "reason": "[1:416] [bool] failed to parse field [should]",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
                "reason": "[1:416] [bool] failed to parse field [must]",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
                    "reason": "[1:416] [bool] failed to parse field [must]",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "parsing_exception",
                        "reason": "[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
                        "line": 1,
                        "col": 416
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I think they use elastic search in backend for apis to work. Elastic search document gives me some JSON object. But I don't know how to convert those JSON objects to a url with query params.

Can someone explain me how can I use multiple query together?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703285/elasticsearch-combine-terms-and-match-query)

Posting that same code here, so that if link is broken in future, we do not loose access to that code:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "color": [
              "red",
              "yellow"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "availability": {
              "query": "in stock"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But that solution was providing an object. I never knew: how to convert that object to query string params.

One of my friend suggested me to use [this converter](https://www.convertonline.io/convert/json-to-query-string) that can covert JSON to Query String params.

I used this input in the converter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "title": "night"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "place_of_origin": "France"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The output that I received from converter:

```
query[bool][must][0][term][title]=night&query[bool][filter][0][match][place_of_origin]=France
```

This solution is working 100% fine, but I am not fully satisfied with the JSON that I got from another answer. So, will not mark my answer as accepted, in hope of someone else posting a better answer. :)